# Calculate function time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of this function

**Code**

```
int Almacen::poner_items(id_sala s, id_producto p, int cantidad){
it_prod r = productos.find(p);
if(r != productos.end()) {
    int n = salas[s - 1].size();
    int m = salas[s - 1][0].size();
    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0 && cantidad > 0; --i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m && cantidad > 0; ++j) {
            if(salas[s - 1][i][j] == "NULL") {
                salas[s - 1][i][j] = p;
                r->second += 1;
                --cantidad;
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    displayError();
    return -1;
}
return cantidad;
```

}

the variable *productos* is a std::map and its find method has a time complexity of Olog(n) and other variable *salas* is a std::vector.
I calculated the time and I found that it was **log(n) + n*m*** but am not sure if it is the correct expression or I should leave it as **nm** because it is the worst or if I whould use n² only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall function is O(nm).  Big-O notation is all about "in the limit of large values" (and ignores constant factors).  "Small" overheads (like an O(log n) lookup, or even an O(n log n) sort) are ignored.

Actually, the O(n log n) sort case is a bit more complex.  If you expect m to be typically the same sort of size as n, then O(nm + nlogn) == O(nm), if you expect n ≫ m, then O(nm + nlogn) == O(nlogn).

Incidentally, this is not a question about C++.

Answer (score 1):

In general when using big O notation, you only leave the most dominant term when taking all variables to infinity.

`n` by itself is much larger than `log n` at infinity, so even without `m` you can (and generally should) drop the `log n` term, so `O(nm)` looks fine to me.

In non-theoretical use cases, it is sometimes important to understand the actual complexity (for non-infinite inputs), since sometimes algorithms that are slow at infinity can produce better results for shorter inputs (there are some examples where O(1) algorithms have such a terrible constant that an exponential algorithm does better in real life). quick sort is considered a practical example of an O(n^2) algorithm that often does better than it's `O(n log n)` counterparts.

Read about "Big O Notation" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

let

```
k = productos.size()
n = salas[s - 1].size()
m = salas[s - 1][0].size()
```

your algorithm is O(log(k) + nm). You need to use a distinct name for each independent variable

Now it might be the case that there is a relation between `k`, `n`, `m` and you can re-label with a reduced set of variables, but that is not discernible from your code, you need to know about the data.

It may also be the case that some of these terms won't grow large, in which case they are actually constants, i.e. O(1).

E.g. you may know `k << n`, `k << m` and `n ~= m` , which allows you describe it as O(n^2)

Comment: There isn't a relation but k is rather small compared to m and n